# Trying to find the title of a novel about a society where people recognize each other by scent

Tags: story-identification, novel, dystopia

I'm trying to remember the title of a sci-fi novel I read back in 2007, maybe later. It was in English and printed in the USA. It was a dystopian future type novel that dealt with an Hispanic type (I think) protagonist who had a mother that was suffering from a disease in which her muscles were solidifying to the point that she was becoming a literal living statue.

It was a highly specialized hive/caste society in which you were identified by BODY SMELLS. if you gave off a certain odor you were recognized for whatever position you were assigned in life. The protagonist learns how to artificially mask his body smells/pheromones(?) in order to move up the societal ladder. I believe the book was called "Claive" or "Glaive" but I can't seem to locate it online. Any help in identifying this novel would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be [Clade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clade_(novel)) by Mark Budz, subject to this [other previous question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/135218/65768).

The idea of pheremone-based social restriction and the main character's ethnicity seem to match. The only element that I wasn't aware of (never having read the book) was the 'living statue' disease, but searching on Google for the title, author and "muscles" gave this fragment of text from Clade's entry on Google books:

> The disease has begun to turn her tendons and muscles into bone, solder her skeleton into a single, rigid piece

which seems to support that part of the plot as well!

Comment: That's the one!! BINGO!! Thanks a bunch for the mental nudge! I KNEW it began with a "C"! Thanks once again.